# Getting workers out of queue slower with multiple processes than single process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

So I have the following code

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue as Queue

def checker(q):
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        if data is None:
            return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    q = Queue()

    for i in range(500000):
        q.put(i)
    procs = []
    for _ in range(4):
        q.put(None)
        p = Process(target=checker, args=(q,), daemon=True)
        # p = Thread(target=checker, args=(q,))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    print(time.time() - t)
```

When I run this program with 4 processes in parallel, it takes around `4.14` seconds to complete, and when it is run with just a single process it takes around `3.7` seconds.

The same thing happens with multiple threads running concurrently.

My possible explanation for this behavior is that since `queues` are `multithreading` and `multiprocessing` safe and have built-in mutex implementation, only one `thread` or `process` can access the queue at one time.

So with a single process/thread, there is no preemption to be done by `python` interpreter or CPU to make sure that every thread/process gets equal opportunity to run their code, but multiple processes/threads the cost of this preemption adds to the overall run time of the program.

So I am thinking on correct lines or is this happening because of something else.

Comment: Could you put on your single process code in the question?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari its the same code, just change the `range(4)` to `range(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not surprising. You aren’t doing anything. So what you are measuring is the overhead of spawning several processes, setting up inter process communication, and marshaling and unmarshaling data over these channels. That’s expensive.

But try doing some actual computation in checker, and the table will quickly flip.